# Keeping track of language in a session variable

Tags: php

What my current code does is, while checking the DB if the versions (FR and EN) are either True or False, display the proper content and if both exist to display a link so that users can switch languages. If only one language exists, the content is shown in that language and there is no link displayed.

the 2 functions in javascript are like this, here`s the FR one:

```
function makeVisibleFR()
{
    document.getElementById('bbqc_contentFR').style.display="inline"; 
    document.getElementById('bbqc_contentEN').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('vFrancais').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('vAnglais').style.display="inline";
}
```

What i`d like to add to this is the option of memorizing the user's choice and displaying the following pages with the same language version.

I imagine i'd need to create a `$_SESSION['language']` variable and store in it either "FR" or "EN" but i`m not sure how to go about implementing that within my current code.

```
<?php
                if($versionFR == true)
                { 
                    if($versionEN == true)
                    {
                ?>
                    <a href="javascript:makeVisibleEN()" id="vAnglais">Version Anglaise</a> 
                    <div id="bbqc_contentFR">
                        <h2><?php echo $titleFR; ?></h2>
                        <?php echo $contentFR; ?>
                    </div>

                    <a href="javascript:makeVisibleFR()" id="vFrancais" style="display:none">Version Française </a>
                    <div style="display:none" id="bbqc_contentEN">
                        <h2><?php echo $titleEN; ?></h2>
                        <?php echo $contentEN; ?>
                    </div>
                <?php 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                ?>
                    <div id="bbqc_contentFR">
                        <h2><?php echo $titleFR; ?></h2>
                        <?php echo $contentFR; ?>
                    </div>
                <?php 
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if($versionEN == true)
                    {
                ?>
                    <div id="bbqc_contentEN">
                        <h2><?php echo $titleEN; ?></h2>
                        <?php echo $contentEN; ?>
                    </div>
                <?php 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                ?>
                    <h2>Erreur, il n`y a aucun texte</h2>
                <?php 
                    }
                }
                ?>
```

Comment: Why don’t you put the language identifier into the URL, e.g. in the path like `/en/…`?

Comment: Because that would involve way too many changes that i'd need hard code into like over 100 pages :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simplistic example:

```
// assuming that databaseHas() queries available languages
session_start();

$langs = array('ENG', 'FR');
$showlang = '';
if (databaseHas($_SESSION['lang']))
{
    $showlang = $_SESSION['lang'];
}
else
{
    foreach ($langs as $l)
    {
        if (databaseHas($l))
        {
            $showlang = $l;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if ($showlang == '')
{
    die('No languages found!');
}

echo databaseContent($showlang);

// print links to alternate languages
foreach ($langs as $l)
{
    if (databaseHas($l) && $l != $showlang)
    {
        // print link to this language
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what i needed to get started, this simple example makes it all clear now, Thanks

Comment: Before printing the link to the alternate language, you should also check to make sure you actually have another language (if you only have English, there shouldn't be a link to French regardless of the user's preference).  I just updated the code to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 0):

put `session_start()` at the top of your file then:

```
if($versionFR == true) $_SESSION['lang'] = 'FR';
else $_SESSION['lang'] = 'ENG';

//later on (could be in a whole other page with session_start() on top)
if($_SESSION['lang'] == 'FR'){/*display FR stuff*/}
elseif($_SESSION['lang'] == 'ENG'){/*display ENG stuff*/}
```

Something like that should work well for ya ^_^

Comment: How would i go about adding that if 1) both versions exist 2) lang is ENG 3) english part is display:none by default

Comment: if both the english and french exists in the database, it will make $versionFR and $versionEN = true, thus going into the 1st and then 2nd if statement display first the FR and a link to the EN

Comment: lol so fig it out, make 2 sess variables and use the same code u have lol

Comment: I guess i'd have to split that section once more to make it check for the $_SESSION first and if the $version exists, to display the link etc.. right?

Comment: something like that, or use more session vars so u dont have to keep redeclaring things on multiple pages

Answer (score 0):

> How would i go about adding that if 1)
>   both versions exist 2) lang is ENG 3)
>   english part is display:none by
>   default

1)  You'd just add the clause: `if($_SESSION['lang'] == 'FR' && $_SESSION['lang'] == 'ENG')`
2)  Not sure what you mean here, Neal explained it well from what I can see
3)  If ENG is display:none by default, you'd want to fire off a javascript function to toggle it back on.

But let's take a step back here, consider this:  Make two language files that define each piece of content. So for your english.php you might have variables such as $GREETING = 'Hello'; $YES = 'YES'; and then in your french.php you'd define these variables as $GREETING = 'Bonjour'; $YES = 'WEE';  (I'm not even sure if wee means yes, but you get the idea!). So now you can choose to include the appropriate language file based on the user's language, and you make it easy to add another language down the road. Be flexible!